# Streamwriter if statement not working

Tags: c#

I am currently working on a school project involving a large number of students where I have to insert a new student alphabetically and do a few other calculations. I am having trouble getting it so that it only adds the new student once. I have an if statement but it doesn't appear to be working properly.

```
`//this adds the new student
        StreamWriter changeFile = new StreamWriter("Students.txt", true);
        string newStudent = "(LIST (LIST 'Malachi 'Constant 'A ) '8128675309 'iwishihadjessesgirl@mail.usi.edu 4.0 )";
        // this is where I am getting stumped
        if (File.Exists(newStudent))
        {
            changeFile.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            changeFile.WriteLine(newStudent);
            changeFile.Close();
        }`
```

Whenever I run the code like this it will just add the new student every time I debug the program. How can I make it only add him one time?

Comment: If you need me to add the Students.txt file, I will need some help, it has over 10,000 students.

Comment: `File.Exists` determines whether the specified file exists. I don't understand what you are trying to achieve, by using it that way

Comment: I have also tried newStudent != null which also doesn't work

Comment: Well sure, it's never null.  We know that because you just set it to a constant (non null) string.

Comment: That's where I am getting stumped, I don't know how to make it check if the string is already in the text file or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`File.Exists` determines if the file at the given path exists (which, for the record, you should still be doing before trying to read/write to the file).  You're trying to find out if the given line of text exists within a given file.  That's a very different task.

You'll need to read through the lines in the file and compare them to your given text.

```
if(!File.ReadLines(filepath).Contains(newStudent))
{
    //TODO: Append student to the file
}
```

Answer (score 1):

File.Exists(string path) returns a bool that determines if a file exists at the specified path.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx

string newStudent is not a file path, so it will always return false.

I think what you want is something like this: (this is by memory so it likely won't compile as is)

```
var file = File.Open("students.txt");
var fileContents = file.ReadToEnd();
if (!fileContents.Contains(newStudent))
{
  file.WriteLine(newStudent);
}
file.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

First read the Existing file data into `String` variable and then check the given student data is available or not in the received file.if the given student data is not found then write the new student data into file otherwise,if already present then  close the opened steream.

```
String StudentInfo = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Students.txt");
    StreamWriter changeFile = new StreamWriter("Students.txt", true);


            string newStudent = "(LIST (LIST 'Malachi 'Constant 'A ) '8128675309 'iwishihadjessesgirl@mail.usi.edu 4.0 )";
            // this is where I am getting stumped
            if (StudentInfo.Contains(newStudent))
            {
                changeFile.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                changeFile.WriteLine(newStudent);
                changeFile.Close();
            }
```